# TypeScript's hashtables and keys with a dash

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to declare a hashtable which includes keys with a dash in TypeScript?

Here's the code i've tried:

```
export interface ImapMessageHeader {
    'mime-version': string[];
    received: string[];
    [index: string]: string[];
}
```

From which i receive the following error:

> Expected identifier in property declaration

The last declaration defining the index type allows me to call any string key, but i can't explicitly define the ones i want to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

This works for me in TypeScript 0.9.5. The [issue is marked as close](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1073) too.

```
interface Foo
{
    "a-1": string;
}

var f: Foo = { "a-1": "hello" };
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoted property names in interface declarations and type literals aren't supported yet, but I believe they will be added in a future release.

Comment: Any updated status on this? This is still not working for me using the 0.9.0 Alpha. I also replaced the typescriptServices.js with the latest 5/23 version and still it didn't work. I thought may be bug 1018 was related. This is needed for mapping to lots of JSON documents.

Comment: Please vote for the issue I just added here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1073